# In Python can isinstance() be used to detect a class method?

Tags: python, class-method, isinstance

How to determine if an object is a class method? Isn't it best practice to use `isinstance()`, and how does one make that work?

```py
class Foo:
    class_var = 0

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls):
        cls.class_var += 1
        print("class variable value:", cls.class_var)


def wrapper(wrapped: classmethod):
    """
    Call the wrapped method.

    :param wrapped (classmethod, required)
    """
    wrapped()

Foo.bar()
wrapper(Foo.bar)
print("the type is:", type(Foo.bar))
print("instance check success:", isinstance(Foo.bar, classmethod))
```

Output:

```
class variable value: 1
class variable value: 2
the type is: <class 'method'>
instance check success: False

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `classmethod` doesn't name the type of method objects. For that you probably want to use `Callable`.

Comment: Because `classmethod` implements the descriptor protocol, you would have to check the `Foo.__dict__['bar']`, as `Foo.bar` produces an instance of `method`.

Comment: While `classmethod` is a type, and applying the `@classmethod` decorator does create a `classmethod` instance from a function, looking that name up in the class later *still gives you an ordinary method instance*. This is due to how the descriptor protocol works. (Though this is really just another way of saying what @chepner said.)

Comment: FYI. Callable returns True for every type of method and also a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to tell class methods apart from regular methods and static methods, then you can check this with `inspect.ismethod(f)`.

```py
class A:
    def method(self): pass
    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls): pass
    @staticmethod
    def static_method(): pass
```

In the REPL:

```py
>>> from inspect import ismethod
>>> ismethod(A.method)
False
>>> ismethod(A.class_method)
True
>>> ismethod(A.static_method)
False
```

If you prefer to do this with `isinstance`, then that's possible using `typing.types.MethodType`:

```py
>>> from typing import types
>>> isinstance(A.method, types.MethodType)
False
>>> isinstance(A.class_method, types.MethodType)
True
>>> isinstance(A.static_method, types.MethodType)
False
```

Note that these tests will incorrectly identify e.g. `A().method` because really we're just testing for a bound method as opposed to an unbound function. So the above solutions only work assuming that you are checking `A.something` where `A` is a class and `something` is either a regular method, a class method or a static method.

Comment: Technically, `isinstance` is testing what each class attribute's `__get__` method returns, not what the class attribute itself is.

Comment: These approaches also correctly return False if fed a function. Bonus points for that.

Answer (score 0):

As you know Python fills the first parameter of the `classmethod`s with a reference to the class itself and it doesn't matter if you call that method from the class or the instance of the class. A method object is a function which has an object bound to it.

That object can be retrieved by `.__self__` attribute. So you can simply check that if the `.__self__` attribute is a class or not. If it is a class , *it's* class is `type`.

#### One way of doing it:

```py
class Foo:

    @classmethod
    def fn1(cls):
        pass

    def fn2(self):
        pass


def is_classmethod(m):
    first_parameter = getattr(m, '__self__', None)
    if not first_parameter:
        return False

    type_ = type(first_parameter)
    return type_ is type


print(is_classmethod(Foo.fn1))
print(is_classmethod(Foo().fn1))
print("-----------------------------------")
print(is_classmethod(Foo.fn2))
print(is_classmethod(Foo().fn2))
```

output:

```
True
True
-----------------------------------
False
False
```

There is a [`ismethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.ismethod) function in inspect module that specifically checks that if the object is a bound method. You can use this as well before checking for the type of the first parameter.

**NOTE**: There is a caveat with the above solution, I'll mention it at the end.

#### Solution number 2:

Your `isinstance` solution didn't work because `classmethod` is a descriptor. If you want to get the actual classmethod instance, you should check the Foo's namespace and get the methods from there.

```py
class Foo:

    @classmethod
    def fn1(cls):
        pass

    def fn2(self):
        pass


def is_classmethod(cls, m):
    return isinstance(cls.__dict__[m.__name__], classmethod)


print(is_classmethod(Foo, Foo.fn1))
print(is_classmethod(Foo, Foo().fn1))
print("-----------------------------------")
print(is_classmethod(Foo, Foo.fn2))
print(is_classmethod(Foo, Foo().fn2))
```

---

**Solution number 1 caveat**: For example if you have a simple `MethodType` object whose bound object is a different class like `int` here, this solution isn't going to work. Because remember we just checked that if the first parameter is of type `type`:

```py
from types import MethodType

class Foo:
    def fn2(self):
        pass
    fn2 = MethodType(fn2, int)

    @classmethod
    def fn1(cls):
        pass
```

Now only solution number 2 works.

Comment: I'd go with Solution #2; Solution #1 depends, I think, on the fact that `classmethod` is the only type that has a `type`-valued `__self__` attribute, rather than being the only type that *can*  have a `type`-valued `__self__` attribute.

Comment: @chepner You're right, I updated the answer and mentioned that with an example.

Comment: is_classmethod(cls, m) crashes if you accidentally feed it a function, so the alternatives are safer.

Comment: @JohnMatecsa `Foo.fn2` is a function and it returns False. How did you test that?